# Neukirch ANT - Reciprocity map doesn't depend on primes

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This is a quick question. Unfortunately, Neukirch does CFT in such a unique way that it is not very easy to explain all the notation and concepts he defined here, so I expect someone who read the book to answer.

In Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, the reciprocity map is defined as follows:

[image]

**Question**

First, why is it true that if we take two primes $\pi_{1},\pi_{2}\in A_{\Sigma}$, then $\pi_{1}=u\cdot\pi_{2}$ for some $u\in U_{\Sigma}$?

(Recall that an element $\pi$ of $A_{K}$ is prime $v_{K}(\pi)=1$ and $U_{\Sigma}=\{u\in A_{K}\:|\:v_{K}(u)=0\}$.

This is not at all obvious to me. We have a formula like $v(ab)=v(a)+v(b)$?

Ok, but meanwhile, I'll accept that his assertion is true.

Still, how can he conclude that $N_{\Sigma/K}(u)\in N_{\widetilde{L} /K}A_{\widetilde{L}}$? I know only that $v(N_{\Sigma/K}(u))=0$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't help with the number theory, but for the LaTeX: if you want to TeX a character with a tilde overtop it you can type either \tilde{L} or \widetilde{L} to produce $\tilde{L}$ and $\widetilde{L}$.

Comment: Edited it. Cheers!

Comment: I think OP already has an answer now. However, I still post it so that future readers of Neukirch might benefit from it. The fact that $v(ab)=v(a)+v(b)$ is implies by definition, because $v: A_k \to \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a **homomorphism** that satisfied certain properties.

Comment: For your second question, the rest of the paragraph actually explains why $N_{\Sigma/K}(u)\in N_{\widetilde{L} /K}A_{\widetilde{L}}$, it used the class field axiom Neukirch assumed at the start of the section.